# Decreasing sequence of normal subgroups of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $G$ be a group. If there exists a
>   sequence of normal subgroups of $G$ $$G=G^{0}\supset
>  G^1\supset\ldots\supset G^n=\{e\}$$ such that the groups $G^k/G^{k+1}$
>   are abelian, then there exists a normal abelian subgroup $A$ of $G$
>   such that $G/A$ is solvable of class $\leq n-1$.

I think the proof is by induction on $n$. I am stuck on the base case $n=1$: suppose $G/\{e\}$ is abelian. This means that $G/\{e\}$ is solvable of class $\leq 1$.

But I have to show that it is solvable of class $\leq n-1=1-1=0$: i.e. that $G/\{e\}=\{e\}$. But why should this follow? What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to show that $G$ is solvable of class $0$. There needs to be an abelian normal subgroup $A$ such that $G/A$ is solvable of class $0$. You can take $A=G$.

Comment: Thank you. For $G=G^0\supset G^1\supset\ldots G^{n+1}=\{e\}$, it is the case that the induction hypothesis holds for $G^1\supset\ldots G^{n+1}=\{e\}$. Then there exists a normal abelian subgroup $A$ of $G^1$ such that $G^1/A$ is solvable of class $\leq n-1$. Is $G^1A$ a good candidate for the normal, abelian subgroup of $G$ with the required property?

Comment: @dixo If I understand correctly, I don't think induction is required. You can just take $A=G^n$.